# Oracle XML-to-SQL query data

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm a novice in oracle and I recently started to work with XML DB, I read about the XMLType storage models and I think the structured storage is the best option for the project, our xml data is highly structured and has a predictable structure.

I registered a schema in oracle (I'm using XE for test purposes) and executed this statement:

```
begin

DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(SCHEMAURL=>'PRODUCTOS.xsd', SCHEMADOC=>'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="LISTA_PRODUCTOS">
          <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="PRODUCTO" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                               <xs:complexType>
                                      <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="articulo"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CE"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cantidad"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="centro"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cliente"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="concepto"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="descripcionProducto"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="espacioM2"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="importe"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="marca"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="medida"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="modelo"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="paquete"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="pesoUnitario"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="precio"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="referencia"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="remolque"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="serie"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="UM"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="valorUnitario"></xs:element>
                                         </xs:sequence>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
</xs:schema>', LOCAL=>true, GENTYPES=>true, GENBEAN=>false, GENTABLES=>true,
FORCE=>false,  OWNER=>'TEST');

commit;

end;
```

and automatically created the objects:

```
LISTA_PRODUCTOS451_TAB (XMLtype STORAGE OBJECT-RELATIONAL TYPE LISTA_PRODUCTOS448_T)
desc LISTA_PRODUCTOS448_T -> PRODUCTO (type PRODUCTO450_COLL)

desc PRODUCTO450_COLL -> articulo VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), CE VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), cantidad VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) ... valorUnitario VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR).
```

If I execute a select on `LISTA_PRODUCTOS448_T` (`select t.getClobVal()` from `LISTA_PRODUCTOS448_T`), I can see all the xml data, but I'm confused, I don't know if it's possible to execute a traditional SQL query and get the data as a simple record set or if is necessary to use the XMLtype functions and procedures using XPath syntax or something else. Why did it create all those objects?

Also, I don't know how to set the memory size of the `LISTA_PRODUCTOS451_TAB` table; if I try to insert 20 xml nodes in a row it saves all the 20 nodes in a single row, and if I attempt to save 1000 the select returns an `ORA-06502: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my English.

Comment: It created the objects because you had `gentypes=>true` (and `gentables=>true`). You're data is stored as an XML document so you'll need to use XPath etc. to get it in a different format. Not sure what you mean about the size though; how are you inserting the '20 xml nodes in a row', ass as one long string? That's a `varchar2` size limit and nothing to do with the table. You'd have to insert each node individually, and you still might need to use CLOB manipulation. Please provide some details. Are you really sure XML is the way to go for this data though?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!
The problem is, i have created a stored procedure to receive the xml data in a parameter (param in XMLtype), so i thought it could be possible to insert the data like another simple INSERT statement [insert into table_name values (param)], by the way the stored procedure is an oracle web service, this sp is being consumed by a SAP application and for every request sap is going to send 10,000 - 20,000 records (or xml nodes).

Comment: OK, so you'll need to decide (or maybe you already have) whether it's better to store it as XML and extract what you need later, or extract everything and store in a normal table; based on what you need to do to and with it. And that might largely depend on whether you need to see it as XML at any point after you receive it.

Comment: It seems that this is more a design problem than a technical one. Thank you Alex.